# Parsing JS dynamicpage with PyQt5

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pyqt5

I am trying to parse the js dynamic page with PyQt5. After execution I get a following error: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005). Code is here:

```
import sys
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
import pandas as pd

class Page(QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebEnginePage.__init__(self)
        self.html = ''
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._on_load_finished)
        self.load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def _on_load_finished(self):
        self.html = self.toHtml(self.Callable)
        print('Load finished')

    def Callable(self, html_str):
        self.html = html_str
        self.app.quit()


url = 'https://www.racingpost.com'

page = Page(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.html, 'html.parser')
courses = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'hidden-sm-down rh-cardsMatrix__courseTitle ui-link'})
for course in courses:
    CurrentCourse = course.text.strip()
    Courses_URL = url + course.get('href')
    response1 = requests.get(Courses_URL)
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(response1.text, 'html.parser')
    horses = soup1.find_all('a', {'class': 'RC-runnerName'})
    for horse in horses:
        horses_url = url + horse.get('href')
        page1 = Page(horses_url)
        soup2 = BeautifulSoup(page1.html, 'html.parser')
        data = soup2.find_all('a', {'class': 'ui-link ui-link_table js-popupLink'})
```

could you please help me with how to rework, or tweak this code in order to get proper info I want.

Comment: I'm able to run your script, I get some JSON and cross site script warnings, but I don't get the error you reported. What version of PyQt5/BS/Python do you use?

Comment: 1) I recommend you execute your code in the console/CMD and indicate the log. 2) Give more information about your environment: exact version of python and the libraries that use your script

Comment: I run this on Windows 10, python ver. 3.8.1, PyQt5.14.1 , BS 4.
This is log output:
js: A parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script, https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/gpt/pubads_impl_2020022701.js, is invoked via document.write. The network request for this script MAY be blocked by the browser in this or a future page load due to poor network connectivity. If blocked in this page load, it will be confirmed in a subsequent console message. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more details.